# how to send push notification in wp7?

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, push-notification, mpns

I am new in push notification and i want to show notification on my wp7 application.

My concept is when web service send me notification so i save this notification in my local database than after display in my page.

I searched more but not get solution

i tries this microsoft link also but here uri is not generated
[How to send and receive toast notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202967%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

I also tried microsoft client push notification but this is not working.

How can i send and receive  notification using web service?

Give me some advice.

**EDITED**

If possible than give me some stap to implement push notification in wp7 at first level

How can i receive notification in my application and how can i handle notification

thanks

Comment: this is very general question

Comment: try [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp). I am using it to send out notifications for ios, android and wp.

Comment: I found a post about that with a sample on GitHub: http://matthiasshapiro.com/2011/06/28/windows-phone-7-push-notification-for-beginnersthe-device/

Comment: @Fabrice:thanks for replay but its same like other i want some demo so i can understand very well or some step wise process so i can understand easily